# How to update MySQL table by swapping two column values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables such that

```
CREATE TABLE guest(
name varchar(100),
ranking int,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(
roomname varchar(100),
wallcolor varchar(100),
rating int,
PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
);

CREATE TABLE reservation(
name varchar(100),
roomname varchar(100),
day varchar(100),
moveinday int,
moveoutday int,
PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
);
```

I'm trying to change all the "Lake" rooms to "Bay" rooms and "Bay" rooms to "Lake" rooms without explicitly changing the rooms involved. How could I do this? I tried using the update query but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: In an UPDATE command instead of giving a particular value to set, use a CASE expression.

Comment: Do you only want to swap the roomnames("bay" , "lake") leaving other properties unchanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE room
SET roomname = (
    CASE
    WHEN roomname = "Bay" THEN
        "Lake"
    WHEN roomname = "Lake" THEN
        "Bay"
    ELSE
        roomname
    END
)
```

**EXample:**

If your room table looks like below before running this query:

[image]

Then after running the above query your room table would look like leaving other rooms unchanged:

[image]